# Wordpress : Allow zip files in media to upload

Tags: php, wordpress, media, wordpress-gutenberg

I need to upload .zip file to media.

Here I tried

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57603/is-it-possible-to-allow-zip-files-to-be-uploaded-in-wordpress

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes');
function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes=array() ) {
    // add your extension to the mimes array as below
    $existing_mimes['zip'] = 'application/zip';
    $existing_mimes['gz'] = 'application/x-gzip';
    return $existing_mimes;
}
```

But it is not working in Wordpress 5+ or gutenburg editor

Comment: can you provide any error messages

Comment: HTTP error. while uploading

Comment: Please post that http error. it will mean a lot of things when you say `http error`

Comment: Well it says only HTTP Error while uploading.

Comment: You need to pass priorities inside your add_filter hook like add_filter('upload_mimes', 'custom_upload_mimes', 999, 1); try this and check.
if it does not work then add define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true ); inside your wp-config.php

Comment: WordPress doesn’t allow us to upload all kinds of files in media library, even for the zip files you get error: “Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.”

Comment: I have answered, please check - @jass Preet

Comment: I already provide you the answer. Can you please try the answer once.

Comment: @itzmekhokan yes it worked but somehow unable to upload zip of only few KBs. Tried also by increasing its memory limit too.

Answer (score 8):

Since WordPress version 4.7.1 ot greater, its added some extra security check for mime types. Just Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php to achieve the above -

```
function modify_upload_mimes ( $mimes_types ) {
    // add your extension to the mimes array as below
    $mimes_types['zip'] = 'application/zip';
    $mimes_types['gz'] = 'application/x-gzip';
    return $mimes_types;
}
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'modify_upload_mimes', 99 );

function add_allow_upload_extension_exception( $types, $file, $filename, $mimes ) {
    // Do basic extension validation and MIME mapping
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, $mimes );
    $ext         = $wp_filetype['ext'];
    $type        = $wp_filetype['type'];
    if( in_array( $ext, array( 'zip', 'gz' ) ) ) { // it allows zip files
        $types['ext'] = $ext;
        $types['type'] = $type;
    }
    return $types;
}
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'add_allow_upload_extension_exception', 99, 4 );
```

For more info visit my blog [link](https://itzmekhokan.wordpress.com/2019/03/28/add-additional-file-types-to-wordpress-media-library/)

Comment: @Jass Preet, it's a working code. First of all tell me in your end is it unable to upload large zip or small zip file.

Answer (score 5):

No need to edit files! You can edit the allowed extensions and add zip in the network settings. 
**My Sites > Network Admin > Settings > Upload file types**

or

```
function zip_upload_mimes($existing_mimes = array()) {
    $existing_mimes['zip'] = 'application/zip';
    $existing_mimes['gz'] = 'application/x-gzip';
    return $existing_mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'zip_upload_mimes', 999, 1);
```

Comment: can you put screenshot where is "Upload file types" menu?

Answer (score 1):

In this case zip is file type extension and application/zip is MIME Type.
If you want to allow other file types you just need to add them in $exisiting_mimes array.

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'add_custom_upload_mimes');
function add_custom_upload_mimes( $existing_mimes ){
$existing_mimes['zip']  = 'application/zip';
$existing_mimes['swf']  = 'application/x-shockwave-flash';
$existing_mimes['rtf']  = 'text/richtext';
$existing_mimes['tiff'] = 'image/tiff';
return $existing_mimes;
}
```

Comment: What error is coming, will you tell the exact please !